# How to make sql connection string in App.config in WPF Browser application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code for the connection string but it doesn't work
can some  one help me regarding to this problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=SONY-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=webolusion_inhouse;User Instance=true; User ID=sa;Password=admin;"/>        
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a reference to System.Configuration?